# vim : iabbrev for a single letter

Tags: vim

in vim if I set

```
 iabbrev @@ mail@myMail.com
```

when I write in insert mode `@@<space>` vim replace `@@` with `mail@mimail.com`.

When I write a tex file and I use a single letter in Upper (A,B,...) this letter should be between `$` ($A$, $B$, ...)

How I can make a `iabbrev` for this ?

I think in some similar to this

```
 ia <space>[A-Z]<space> <space>$[A-Z]$<space>
```

Comment: And how will you write the first-person subjective case personal pronoun efficiently?

Comment: I write in spanish, I don't need the "I"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to create 26 abbreviations:

```
for ch in range(char2nr("A"),char2nr("Z"))
    execute "ia ".nr2char(ch)." $".nr2char(ch)."$"
endfor
```

Comment: I modify "ai ..." to "ai <buffer> ..." ;)